# How to modify java Date to a specific time?

Tags: java, shell, jenkins, groovy

I am running a script in Jenkins. One piece of the script need to run at 07:00:00 Eastern Time.

The job is already scheduled on specific days and time. The job starts at 6am, but need to wait until 7am to run the next step

Using java, I can get current time/date using:

```
Date currentDate = new Date()
```

I think I need to compare currentDate with today's date at 7am so I can know how many seconds there is until 7am and put my build to sleep for that time.

My question is, how can I generate today's date at 7am?

Comment: "My question is, how can I generate today's date at 7am?" - Does `new Date().copyWith(hourOfDay: 7, minute: 0, second: 0)` give you what you want?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: 7 AM in which time zone?

Comment: "7 AM in which time zone?" - The question indicates "One piece of the script need to run at 07:00:00 Eastern Time."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid using the terrible `Date` class. The legacy date-time classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Capture the current moment as seen in your particular time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Define your target.

```
LocalTime targetTime = LocalTime.of( 7 , 0 ) ;
```

Adjust to that time.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtTarget = zdt.with( targetTime ) ;
```

If that moment has passed, move to next day.

```
if( ! zdt.isBefore( zdtTarget ) ) {
    zdtTarget = zdt.toLocalDate().plusDays( 1 ).atStartOfDay( z ).with( targetTime ) ;
}
```

Determine time to elapse.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( zdt.toInstant() , zdtTarget.toInstant() ) ;
```

Interrogate the duration object for whatever you need. For example, milliseconds:

```
long millis = d.toMillis() ;
Thread.sleep( millis ) ;
```

If you must use a `java.until.Date` for code not yet updated to *java.time*, you can convert.

```
java.until.Date date = Date.from( zdtTarget.toInstant() ) ;
```

Comment: This worked great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Great question.  It's easier to first create a Calendar object to set up the time, date and other custom inputs, then convert that to a Date object using the <CALENDAR_OBJECT>.getTime() member function.
EX: to get a Date object of 7 am today(10/25/2021) do the following:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // Calendar constructor
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2021);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 25);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,7);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,00);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);

Date d = cal.getTime(); // convert to Date obj
```

For more info on the Calendar obj look at some documentation by Oracle (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Comment: Thank you, the only thing I changed is instead of setting myself Year, month and day. I am using cal.setTime(new Date())

Comment: This code ignores the crucial issue of time zone.

Comment: "cal.setTime(new Date())" - is that better than just `Calendar.instance`?